# Definition of convex combination with matrix-vector multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

Is there any similar definition to "convex combination of vectors", for the case of matrix coefficient not the scalars?

E.g.,

$${\bf w} = {\bf (I-A) v} + {\bf A u }$$

What conditions does $\bf A$ need to satisfy to make it a "convex combination"? Is there any book introducing such topic?

Comment: This could be interesting if $\bf A$ were a projection matrix

Answer (score 0):

Not one that I know of. Usually, the notion of a convex set is defined as follows: Let $V$ be a vector space over the field $\mathbb{R}$. Then $X\subset V$ is convex (in $V$) if for all $x,y \in X$ and for all $\theta \in (0,1)$, $\theta x + (1-\theta)y \in V$.

People usually introduce machinery when they are interested in solving a particular problem. Is your question linked to a particular problem that you can share with us?

Comment: Basically, we want to see if S is a convex set, and **u**, **v** are in S, what conditions we need on **A** so that (**I**-**A**) **u** + **A** **v** is also in S?

Comment: Well, all you can really say is something about convex combinations. For example, suppose $S$ was JUST the points on the line connecting $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$. $S$ is obviously convex, so we're back to convex combinations only! If you want to be able to say more, you're going to have to restrict your set $S$ to have more properties w.r.t. two arbitrary points in it.

Comment: And if you want to write your convex combinations as matrix, then $A=\theta I$ where $\theta \in [0,1]$ (this is identical to what I wrote above).

Answer (score 0):

Since a couple of years ago, I was looking for the same thing you are asking for. I found that what I was looking for is actually an affine map. This structure generalizes convex combination to matrix form:
$$f(x) = Ax + b,$$
where $A$ is an affine transoformation matrix. When $A\in\mathbb{S}$, $A$ is an ellipsoid.

See here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation#Representation,
and for more details read about ellipsoids on Boyd's Convex Optimization book.

I hope this helps.